# Is there a method to let text be responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

My biggest problem in web development is to let the page be responsive. What I only want is that the text's size adjusts to the screen size. I know the values vw an vh, but it's still not the same, although I work with vw and vh all the time. I want a formula or something like that. I saw a something on the internet, that makes your text responsive but I don't really know how to use it. It is something like that:

```
font-size: clamp(20px, calc(20px + (50 - 20) * ((100vw - 420px) / (1200 - 420))), 60px);
```

I would be really happy, if someone would give me an answer.

Comment: You can certain change your web app so the content does not move or resize or wrap when the screen/viewport changes. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using VW for sizing when you are changing the screen size your project text sizes changes use rem instead of vw

Comment: There is nothing in the question about text/font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `bootstrap Grids` for example if you want two `div's` to be `inline` you should use `col-6` for each `parent` and it'll be responsive